# Stopping Angular Activity Monitor (sean3z)

Tags: angularjs

Does anyone know how to correctly unsubscribe from the Activity Monitoring? I have been trying the notes on the github page, but to no avail. I am trying to turn off monitoring when user sign out from web app.

http://sean3z.github.io/angular-activity-monitor/

```
    service.stopActivityMonitor = function() {
        // Trying to trigger this UNSUBSCRIBE when LOGOUT is CLICKED
        ActivityMonitor.off('inactive', function() {
            <Function process for app LOGOUT>
        });
    };

    service.startActivityMonitor = function() {
        ActivityMonitor.on('inactive', function() {
            // User is considered inactive
            <Sign Off Sequence when user is INACTIVE>
            // if session expires on dash stop time

            $mdDialog.show({
                locals: {dataToPass: vm},
                controller: SessionController,
                controllerAs: 'vm',
                templateUrl: '/components/login/session.expire.dialog.html',
                parent: angular.element(document.body),
                clickOutsideToClose: false
            });
            $state.go('home');
        });

        ActivityMonitor.on('keepAlive', function() {
            <Function to keep session OPEN>
        });

        ActivityMonitor.on('warning', function() {
            $mdDialog.show({
                locals: {dataToPass: vm},
                controller: SessionController,
                controllerAs: 'vm',
                templateUrl: '/components/login/session.inactive.dialog.html',
                parent: angular.element(document.body),
                clickOutsideToClose: false
            });
        });
    };
```

Does this help?

Comment: Could you provide a link to said github page? There is a lot of them! Also if we can see what you've tried so far that would be great.

Comment: Added link to github repo. I don't have any examples at this time I blew away the code I had. But I will try to replicate above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully I can provide some insight as the original creator of this module :)

There's a few ways to stop the activity monitor but, manually configuring the `ActivityMonitor.options.enabled` property is discouraged since it doesn't actually unregister the DOM listeners or clear the inactivity checks. While setting the property technically "works", going this route essentially keeps the service alive and looking for user activity but, shortcuts further action due a (well placed) check on the `enabled` property.

If you really need to stop/unsubscribe, consider the following routes:

#### Use `ActivityMonitor.disable()`

Apologies that this appears to be undocumented at the moment but, `disable()` is the preferred method for discontinuing the entire service all together. This will unregister the DOM listeners, clear all inactivity timeouts and mark the service as disabled.

If you just want to remove a single event (and keep other events active/alive), you'll need to use the method below.

#### (Un)subscribing and Event namespacing

I noticed your example:

```
ActivityMonitor.off('inactive', function() {
  <Function process for app LOGOUT> /* this is incorrect */
});
```

In order to unsubscribe from a single event, you essentially have three options:

- Pass the ***same*** callback argument to `.unbind()` or `.off()`
- Subscribe and unsubscribe using event namespacing.
- Unsubscribe all callbacks for a particular event

*same callback example*

```
var foo = function() {
  alert("y0, you're inactive!");
};
ActivityMonitor.on('inactive', foo); /* subscribe */
ActivityMonitor.off('inactive', foo); /* unsubscribe */
```

*event namespace example*

Instead of maintaining references to callbacks in order to unbind them, we can namespace the events and use this capability to easily unbind our actions. Namespaces are defined by using a period (.) character when binding to an event:

```
ActivityMonitor.on('inactive.myEvent', function foo() {
  alert("y0, you're inactive!");
});
ActivityMonitor.off('inactive.myEvent');
```

*unsubscribe all example*

If you want to remove all callbacks for the `inactivity` event (or others), you can simply just pass the event without the second argument.

```
ActivityMonitor.off('inactive');
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I needed to be much clearer with my question. I wanted to end the Activity Monitor session when the user clicked the Logout Button. Unsubscribing was not what I needed accomplished!

My solution was to set the property **enabled** to false to stop Activity Monitor from continuing after the user had sign off. Here is my code:

```
    service.endInactivityCheck = function() {
        ActivityMonitor.options.enabled = false;
    };
```

My apologies for the confusion. Thanks!